# Check if Date from Array of Dates is Date in Today (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, class, date

I've got an array of 'reminders'. Reminder is a custom class that I wrote by myself which has got a property .fireDate.

How could I check if one of the reminders .fireDate properties is the same date as today?

Comment: edit your question  and paste relevant code here

Answer (score 2):

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
for (idx, date) in dates.enumerated() {
    if calendar.isDateInToday(date) {
        print("today at index \(idx)!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! And how would I get the index of the object that matches the date in the array?

Comment: Simply use `enumerated()` function :)

Answer (score 1):

Get the index of the first item whose `fireDate` is in today. If it's not `nil` there is at least one item.

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
if let indexOfFirstReminderWhichFiresToday = reminders.index(where: { calendar.isDateInToday($0.fireDate) }) {
    print("\(reminders[indexOfFirstReminderWhichFiresToday]) fires today")
}
```

Comment: Just use `contains(where:)` instead

Comment: Thanks, that's amazing! Didn't even know there was a method like that^^

Comment: `!= nil` sucks. There are `guards` and `if let` to avoid working with nil. :)

Comment: @Alexander The OP seems to need also the index of the item.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the dates in today:

`let todayDates = arrayOfDates.filter { Calendar.current.isDateInToday($0) }`